# Алиас типа функции-члена класса

Tags: c++, классы

```
#include <iostream>

struct S {
    using Func = int();
    Func f {
        return 42;
    }
};


int main() {
    S s;
    std::cout << s.f() << '\n';
}
```

> error: invalid initializer for member function 'int S::f()'

Почему этот код не компилируется? Как сделать, чтобы компилировался?

Comment: Текст ошибки компилятора тоже надо выложить - не у всех в голове есть синтаксический анализатор

Comment: @gbg добавил, не ставьте минусы

Comment: @user207200 `int()` это тип функции без параметров с возвращаемым `int`

Answer (score 1):

Определение функции сделано неправильно. В такой ситуации оно должно быть вне класса и использовать обычный синтаксис:

```
#include <iostream>

struct S
{
    using Func = int();
    Func f;
};

int S::f()
{
    return 42;
}

int main()
{
    S s;
    std::cout << s.f() << '\n';
}
```

[online compiler](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:22,endLineNumber:5,positionColumn:22,positionLineNumber:5,selectionStartColumn:22,selectionStartLineNumber:5,startColumn:22,startLineNumber:5),source:%27%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%0Astruct+S%0A%7B%0A++++using+Func+%3D+int()%3B%0A++++Func+f%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aint+S::f()%0A%7B%0A++++return+42%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++S+s%3B%0A++++std::cout+%3C%3C+s.f()+%3C%3C+!%27%5Cn!%27%3B%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g112,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B17+-Wall+-Wextra+-Wconversion+-Wshadow+-Wpedantic+-Werror%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+11.2+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

Comment: т.е. алиас типа можно использовать только при объявлении функции, а при определении - нет

Answer (score 0):

f - это не функция, а переменная, которая должна хранить функцию. Поэтому, весь синтаксис и не нравится компилятору. Исправим

```
#include <iostream>

struct S {
    using Func = int();
    // нужен указатель на функцию, что бы сохранить
    // и добавим туда лямбду, что бы попроще.
    Func *f { +[](){return 42;} };
};


int main() {
    S s;
    std::cout << s.f();
}
```